# Unknown action, Ruby on Rails 4 Beginner, destroy action is unknown

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, destroy

I get " The action  could not be found for ArticleController " After pressing "delete It", on my delete page. I think it can not find destroy function! What is missing here?

Controller:

```
class ArticleController < ApplicationController

def index
  @article= Article.all
end

def show
  @article= Article.find(params[:id])
end

def new
 @article= Article.new
end

def create
  @article= Article.new(user)

  if @article.save
      redirect_to(:action => 'index')
  else
      redirect_to(:action => 'index')
  end
end

def delete
  @article= Article.find(params[:id])
end

def destroy
  article.find(params[:id]).destroy
  redirect_to(:action => 'index')
end

private
  def user
  params.require(:article).permit(:title, :text)
  end
end
```

The routes.rb

```
 Rails.application.routes.draw do

  resources :article 
   match ':controller(/:action(/:id))', :via => [:get, :post]
  #..
```

my delete.html.erb

```
  <h2>Delete</h2>

  <%= form_for :article, :url => url_for(:action => 'destroy', :id => @article) do |f| %>
    <%= @article.title %>
    <%= submit_tag("Delete It") %>
  <% end %>
```

Comment: I don't think you need the match line in your routes file. resources create the 7 restful paths

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see a few things wrong with the code you posted.

First, your controllers should be the plural name of your resource so in this case it should be `ArticlesController`.

Second, in regards to the error you're getting, when using `resources :articles` in your routes file the destroy action is mapped to a `DELETE` request. Your form is trying to `GET` the destroy action.

What you'll want to do to fix that is

```
<%= form_for :article, :url => url_for(:action => 'destroy', :id => @article), :method => :delete do |f| %>
```

Take a look at the [Rails Routing Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) for more information on how Rails uses REST.

Comment: Thanks, I did change the delete.html and now it is working. I haven't changed the name of controller to plural, what if I keep it singular?

Comment: @Zaeim It should be kept plural.Check the Naming Conventions of Rails.http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html#naming-conventions

Answer (score 1):

Firstly,your `destroy` method is not valid and not necessary.Remove it from the controller.

change your `delete` methods as

```
def delete
  @article= Article.find(params[:id])
  if @article.destroy
  redirect_to(:action => 'index')
  else
  render 'delete'
end
```

And finally,change your `form_for` as

```
<%= form_for :article, :url => url_for(:action => 'delete', :id => @article) do |f| %>
    <%= @article.title %>
    <%= submit_tag("Delete It") %>
  <% end %>
```

**Note:** And also as @brendon mentioned,change your controller name to **plural**.As per now it is **singular** which is against the naming conventions of Rails.

Comment: He should instead keep `ArticlesController#destroy` and remove `ArticlesController#delete` since the latter isn't the Rails standard.

Comment: @BrandonCordell you are right.But the logic in the destroy method which the OP has seems wrong to me. Isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

Change the code in your delete.html.erb to

```
<h2>Delete</h2>

<%= @article.title %> <%= button_to 'Delete It', article, method: :delete %>
```